# Wordpress Search Function With Mutiple Text Inputs

Tags: wordpress, forms, search

I need to create a wordpress search function with multiple text inputs

This is the code I have right now, which works fine. It searches for the keyword in the custom post type of "project_posts"

```
<form role="search" action="/" method="get" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Projects"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="project_posts" />
        <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

But what I want is something like this, with multiple text inputs.

```
<form role="search" action="/" method="get" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Keyword"/>
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Location"/>
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Category"/>
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Material"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="project_posts" />
        <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

This is how the client wants it, so that's what I need to provide.

Unfortunately, this code doesn't quite work. It generates this URL
example.com/?s=&s=&s=&s=&post_type=project_posts
And it only uses whatever is in the last search box for the actual search.

I'm a bit stuck with this one, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with name="s[]"

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Could you post the code handling the form ?

Comment: This is searchform.php in my Wordpress theme. This replaces the default Wordpress search form. It uses the WP_Query function to run the actual search

Comment: @Jellyspoons - did you solve this? I need to do the same thing and can't find an answer when all my search fields need to be text inputs.